# Put formula with if statements in the entire columns

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have recorded a macro with the following formula, but it gives me an error in the second line.

> Expected end of statement.

I guess the issue is that its way to long. Please suggest how to make this work?

Sub Macro1()

```
    Range("CG2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC69=""High"",(IF(AND(RC4<>"""",RC5<>"""",RC6<>"""",RC7<>"""",RC8<>"""",RC10<>"""",RC11<>"""",RC12<>"""",RC13<>"""",RC14<>"""",RC16<>"""",RC17<>"""",RC18<>"""",RC19<>"""",RC20<>"""",RC21<>"""",RC22<>"""",RC23<>"""",RC24<>"""",RC25<>"""",RC26<>"""",RC27<>"""",RC28<>"""",RC29<>"""",RC30<>"""",RC31<>"""",RC32<>"""",RC33<>"""",RC34<>"""",RC35<>"""",RC36<>"""",RC37<>"""",RC38<>"""",RC39<>"""",RC40<>"""",RC41<>"""",RC42<>"""",RC43<>"""",RC44<>"""",RC45<>"""",RC46<>""""),""No"",""Yes""))," & Chr(10) & "(IF(RC69=""Medium"",(IF(AND(RC4<>"""",RC5<>"""",RC6<>"""",RC7<>"""",RC8<>"""",RC10<>"""",RC11<>"""",RC12<>"""",RC13<>"""",RC14<>"""",RC16<>"""",RC17<>"""",RC18<>"""",RC19<>"""",RC20<>"""",RC21<>"""",RC22<>"""",RC23<>"""",RC31<>"""",RC32<>"""",RC33<>"""",RC34<>"""",RC35<>"""",RC36<>"""",RC37<>"""",RC38<>"""",RC39<>"""",RC40<>"""",RC41<>"""",RC42<>"""",RC44<>"""",RC45<>"""",RC46<>""""),""No"",""Yes""))," & Chr(10) & "(IF(AND(RC4<>"""",RC5<>"""",RC6<>"""",RC7<>"""",RC8<>"""",RC10<>"""",RC11<>"""",RC12<>""""
""",RC14<>"""",RC16<>"""",RC17<>"""",RC18<>"""",RC19<>"""",RC20<>"""",RC31<>"""",RC32<>"""",RC33<>"""",RC34<>"""",RC35<>"""",RC36<>"""",RC37<>"""",RC38<>"""",RC39<>"""",RC41<>"""",RC42<>"""",RC45<>"""",RC46<>""""),""No"",""Yes"")))))"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is the multiples `"`, and you also have a different kind of these : `“` which do not work!

So replace the `"` by `Chr(34)` like this :

```
Sub formula()
Range("CO2:CO").formula = "=IF(OR(LEN($BN2)=0;$BN2=" & Chr(34) & "Not Performed" & Chr(34) & _
            ";LEN($BK2)=0;$BK2=" & Chr(34) & "Not Performed" & Chr(34) & _
            ";LEN($BL2)=0;$Q2=" & Chr(34) & "Not Performed" & Chr(34) & _
            ";LEN($BM2)=0);" & Chr(34) & "Yes" & Chr(34) & ";" & Chr(34) & _
            "No" & Chr(34) & ")"
End Sub
```

Comment: I got the formula by simply putting the formulae and recording a macro.So i get them in the right format. Thank you for the help.